# Gnuplot timestamp color?

Tags: colors, timestamp, gnuplot

I have a system doing several plots with gnuplot and after a platform-change went to black background in graphics. Problem is, I'm not able to get the text on timestamp to be white.

Would love to have a timestamp but black text on black background is, well, a bit dull :)

This is frim my .plot:

```
#set colors
set border linecolor rgbcolor "white"
set key textcolor rgbcolor "white"
set ylabel textcolor rgbcolor "white"
set y2label textcolor rgbcolor "white"
set xlabel textcolor rgbcolor "white"
set title textcolor rgbcolor "white"
set timestamp color rgbcolor "white"
set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1
set obj 1 fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor rgbcolor "black"
```

And timestamp is at the moment

```
#insert timestamp to upper left corner    
set timestamp "%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S" top offset -1,-1 font ",10"
```

I've tried everything possible in my mind, so do You have any ideas left?

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, that `set timestamp` doesn't support `textcolor`. As workaround you can set a label and format the time with `strftime`:

```
set label left at character 1, graph 1.05 strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M:%S", time(0)) tc rgb "white"
```

That works fine with 4.6.3.

That may need some tweaking of the position an maybe of the top margin (I don't know if the timestamp is considered when calculating the top margin, a label is definitely not).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! This approach works like a charm, thank You!